# r - for loop to compare 2 dataframes all by all rows

Tags: r, for-loop, compare

I'm trying to compare 2 columns from dataframe `d1` with 2 columns from dataframe `d2`, row by row. To illustrate the issue I created dummy datasets:

```
d1 <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,2,3),
  b = c(4,5,6)
)

d2 <- data.frame(
  a = c(2,0,2),
  b = c(5,5,6)
)
```

Ideally, I would like to flag all rows in `d1` for which I can find a match in at least one row of `d2`, so the wanted result would be:

```
data.frame(
  a = c(1,2,3),
  b = c(4,5,6),
  flag = c(0,1,0)
)
```

this is what I tried:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(d1)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(d2)) {
    test[i,j] = ifelse(d1$a[i] == d2$a[j] & d1$b[i] == d2$b[j], 1, 0)
  }
}
```

a for loop would be the best solution

Comment: because there is no row in d2 where a=3 and b=6

Answer (score 3):

You are basically looking for a kind of join. For this special task, flagging only, `data.table` is very neat here with the in-place join and update

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- data.table(
  a = c(1,2,3),
  b = c(4,5,6)
)

d2 <- data.table(
  a = c(2,0,2),
  b = c(5,5,6)
)


# assign 1 to each match in place
d1[d2,
   on = .(a, b),
   flag := 1]
d1
#>    a b flag
#> 1: 1 4   NA
#> 2: 2 5    1
#> 3: 3 6   NA

# convert NAs to zeros
d1[is.na(flag), flag := 0]
d1
#>    a b flag
#> 1: 1 4    0
#> 2: 2 5    1
#> 3: 3 6    0
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I would prefer a for loop due to the complexity of the join that is not currently provided by data.table

Comment: What do you mean? Please provide an actual example of your problem

Comment: i would need to use stringr::str_detect(d1$a[i], d2$a[j])

Comment: Please provide an actual example of your actual problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208542/r-for-loop-to-compare-2-dataframes-all-by-all-rows-with-custom-matching-functi

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` for this:

```
d1$flag <- match(paste0(d1$a, d1$b), paste0(d2$a, d2$b), nomatch = 0)
```

Edit: @mnist raises a fair point. Here is an alternative that works more securely for NA rows:

```
d1$flag <- as.numeric(duplicated(rbind(d2, d1)))[-seq_len(nrow(d1))]
```

Comment: neat yet prone to errors since `paste0("a", "")` and `paste0("", "a")` would be equivalent.

Comment: Very good point. I added an alternative that should circumvent that, it's just a bit less readable